# IIS7 logging options - Difference between Server and Site level

Tags: iis, web-server, options

I am setting up my first IIS 7.5 server and have come unstuck.  Is there a difference between the server logging options and site logging options.

I am assuming that the server logging options relate to creating a template for all sites to follow so that you don't have to go into the logging options pane on each site.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

The server-level options panel for the logging module allows you to set a default logging configuration for any new sites, as well as to re-apply it to existing sites with non-conforming configurations.

I'll also note that this kinda-inheritance of the server level logging settings is different from the "one log file per server/site" option dropdown, which is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - I was going mad looking for a 2nd log file :)